# Evaluating an integral combining a Bessel function with some other functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

How can I evaluate the integral of $j_1 ^2(x)\exp(-bx)/x$ from 0 to ∞?

Answer (score 8):

If you mean the Bessel function $J_1(x)$:

```
Assuming[b > 0,
  Integrate[BesselJ[1, x]^2*Exp[-b x]/x, {x, 0, ∞}]]
```

> (π + b^2 EllipticE[-4/b^2] - (4 + b^2) EllipticK[-4/b^2])/(2π)

If you mean the spherical Bessel function $j_1(x)$, it's a bit harder:

```
J[b_, x_] = Integrate[SphericalBesselJ[1, x]^2*Exp[-b x]/x, x];
Assuming[b > 0,
  Limit[J[b, x], x -> ∞] - Limit[J[b, x], x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] // FullSimplify]
```

> 1/96 (-4 (-6 + b^2) - 32 b ArcTan[2/b] + b^2 (12 + b^2) (-2 Log[b] + Log[-2 I + b] + Log[2 I + b]))

The last line can be simplified to

> 1/96 (-4 (-6 + b^2) - 32 b ArcTan[2/b] + b^2 (12 + b^2) Log[1 + 4/b^2])

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you please provide me the steps for the solution of the integration.

Comment: @ParveenBano you're on the wrong forum for that (this forum is about the *Mathematica* software). Maybe ask at the [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion